# rotate image continuously with javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation

I would like to write a javascript to continuously rotate image by clicking on a button. I was able to make a partial rotation with a click. I think I should recursively call the function to obtain a continuously rotation but I don't know how to do this.
The following is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Rotation</title>
</head>

<body>
        <button id="rotate">Rotate</button>
    <img src="images/circle.png" id="sample" ;" alt="" />
    
</body>

<script>
var rotation = 0;


document.querySelector("#rotate").addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    rotation += 90;

    
    document.querySelector("#sample").style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';
});
            
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own (e.g. `setInterval()`)? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: a CSS animation would be better

Answer (score 0):

add a class in your css file like

```css
.rotating {
   animation: rotate 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
   from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
   to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

and then add that class by javascript to your element

```js
document.querySelector("#rotate").addEventListener('click', function() {
   document.querySelector("#sample").classList.add('rotating')
});
```

Comment: But why `359deg`?

Comment: I always do this, because `360deg` is the same amount of rotation as `0deg`. So if you rotate to `360deg` you will have two frames at the exact same position and it will look like it stucks for a short moment after one rotation. @HaoWu

Comment: No it won't... `0deg` to `360deg` is perfect for a continuous rotate animation. As long as the timing function is `linear`. Then why it's `359deg` but not `359.9deg` or `359.99deg`?

Comment: @HaoWu not sure, maybe you're right. i used to do this all the time because i once faced an issue where i had a frame where the rotation was stuck and this was my workaround for it. https://codepen.io/puerschel93/pen/eYRJZBr in my example you can't see any difference actually